# tcmalloc's fragmentation

Tags: c++, linux, glibc, fragmentation, tcmalloc

Our software implement a actor model system, and we allocate/deallocate the small object very often.I am very sure the each object be destroyed without memory leak. ( I have used valgrind and tcmalloc tool to check the memory leak in my software. No leak be found.)

When we change to use tcmalloc for replacing the malloc in glibc, we found the memory continually increasing until the process be killed by OOM(Out of Memory).
Then we found glibc also have same issue, but increase rate is less than tcmalloc.

I used the malloc_stats() to show the memory information

after first execution(top show 0.96G)'

---

- MALLOC:    960110592 (  915.6 MB) Heap size
- MALLOC:     15886016 (   15.2 MB) Bytes in use by application
- MALLOC:    907419648 (  865.4 MB) Bytes free in page heap
- MALLOC:            0 (    0.0 MB) Bytes unmapped in page heap
- MALLOC:     27121208 (   25.9 MB) Bytes free in central cache
- MALLOC:       151040 (    0.1 MB) Bytes free in transfer cache
- MALLOC:      9532680 (    9.1 MB) Bytes free in thread caches
- MALLOC:        14275              Spans in use
- MALLOC:           27              Thread heaps in use
- MALLOC:      7602176 (    7.2 MB) Metadata allocated

---

### After 5th same execution(top show 1.2G)

- MALLOC:   1173131264 ( 1118.8 MB) Heap size
- MALLOC:     18001048 (   17.2 MB) Bytes in use by application
- MALLOC:   1082458112 ( 1032.3 MB) Bytes free in page heap
- MALLOC:     21168128 (   20.2 MB) Bytes unmapped in page heap
- MALLOC:     37992328 (   36.2 MB) Bytes free in central cache
- MALLOC:       252928 (    0.2 MB) Bytes free in transfer cache
- MALLOC:     13258720 (   12.6 MB) Bytes free in thread caches
- MALLOC:        17651              Spans in use
- MALLOC:           27              Thread heaps in use
- MALLOC:      8126464 (    7.8 MB) Metadata allocated

---

We can seen from thus data.
after 5th same behavior, only 17.2 be used in our software. But the tcmalloc hold 1.1G memory without return to system. Of course, It does not matter tcmalloc hold those memory.
But it keep increasing when our program be killed by OOM(actual used memory is less than 1G).

We have doubt that it is related to heap fragmentation.
Anybody have some experience could share with us?
I think I have same situation as 
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=843478

Thanks very much.

Comment: Why are you so sure there is absolutely no memory leaks???

Comment: "I am very sure the each object be destroyed without memory leak." Im very sure that there is a greater chance of bug in your code than in the tcmalloc. :) Like A says try valgrind, it is quite easy to run actually

Comment: BTW, what software are you developing? Is it free software? I am interested in actor systems implemented in C or C++....

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Yes, I have used valgrind and tcmalloc tool to check the memory leak in my software. No leak be found.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl Also, after each execution we may added some cache for store something. Bug according to "18001048 ( 17.2 MB) Bytes in use by application" which reported by malloc_stats(), i am sure we could not hold such a large number of memory to make OS kill this process by OOM.

Comment: this is higely unlikely but maybe your usage pattern really messes up with tcmalloc algs and is has a huge overhead per each byte you actually allocate... again doesnt feel really realistic.

Comment: btw there is one thing about tcmalloc that puzzled me a long time ago:  "TCMalloc currently does not return any memory to the system. " but it should still reuse freed memory...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Perhaps `tcmalloc` never calls `munmap`

Comment: btw one more leet technique... use CRTP to count alive instances of your objects if you have low amound of diff objects

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Boehm's conservative GC](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) and use `GC_MALLOC` and `GC_MALLOC_ATOMIC` instead of `malloc` in your application (and `GC_FREE` instead of `free`, but you could then even avoid any explicit `free`-ing, the GC would do them). Or maybe use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (with the system Glibc malloc) to find memory leaks. If using Boehm's GC, don't forget to explicitly clear the allocated memory zones.

It would be preferable to make sure that your many small objects have coarse grained sizes. E.g. allocate objects of 8 or 12 or 16 words, not objects of 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 or 16 words... For instance, you might allocate only zones of size some power of 2 or 3 times a power of 2.

Also, don't forget you can limit the memory space with [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html), e.g. with the `ulimit` builtin of the bash running in your terminal. This should ease testing. Also, perhaps using `pmap` or `/proc/$(pidof yourapp)/maps` could help you to understand the address space used.

PS. Neither Boehm GC, nore any kind of `malloc` (including `tcmalloc` or Glibc `malloc`) can tackle with memory fragmentation. If you suspect fragmentation you have to move memory zones in the address space (i.e. you may want to code your own precise, copying, generational GC or re-use some existing one).

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I have used valgrind and tcmalloc tool to check the memory leak in my software. No leak be found. I think GC and fixed size object may resolve some question. But we already have manager the object in our software using reference_count in C++. So it is very hard to do thus big change.

Comment: Then you might indeed be hurt by memory fragmentation, and you cannot do much easily (because you need to move memory zones). If you have some persistence mechanism, you could persist your state on file, stop the program, and restart it with the persisted state on disk.

Answer (score 1):

tcmalloc tries to do some smart things to anticipate your memory use, but it isn't very good about releasing memory back to the system even after you have freed it. in fact, it might be resident in memory and leading to OOM.

do this :

MallocExtension::instance()->ReleaseFreeMemory();

when your application has expectedly freed memory that it expects to not use soon.

look at the section "Releasing memory back to the system" for more information
http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html

there are other methods, such as setting the Release rate, but as a start you can sprinkle this in your code and inspect if resident memory goes down as you expect.